# taxonomy_template filter not working on pagination

Tags: plugins, filters

I have the below filter in my register method that will pull in a specific template file based on a custom taxonomy:

```
add_filter('taxonomy_template', function($template) {
    if (is_tax( 'recipe-categories')) {
        $template = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/mu-plugins/sacfoodies/templates/recipe-taxonomy-single.php';
    }

    return $template;
});
```

It pull in all the recipe-categories slugs and displays the proper template as shown below:

> /recipe-categories/bread/
>   /recipe-categories/breakfast/

But, I'm attempting to add pagination to the custom taxonomy template and I'm getting a 404 error, so if the URL is /recipe-categories/bread/page/2, the template is not detected anymore.

Comment: Are you creating a brand new query inside that template via `get_posts`,  `WP_Query` or `query_posts` to change the posts WP displays? Is `recipe-categories` a page? Or is it the slug of the custom taxonomy? Note that what you're doing with `mu-plugins` is highly unusual

Comment: @TomJNowell, it's the code that you just previously commented on - So I have the above code inside my register method and `/recipes` is my page, which displays the custom taxonomy categories which are slugs such as `/recipe-categories/bread`, etc.. The developer that I'm working with does it all inside mu-plugins because of theme changes.

Comment: @Sem Your issue has nothing to do with whether or not it can find the template. Tom described your issue in his comment on your previous question. You need to follow those directions.